# avoid duplicating in Sequelize, Nodejs & Reactjs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I am using

1. nodejs with
2. sequelize
3. reactjs

**, the question is How to avoid duplicating in sequelize, I have a registration form as following

```
fullName
emad_address
password
```

and I don't want to have duplicate emails and fullName:
here is the code.

```
  module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      const Users = sequelize.define("Users", {
        fullName: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
        },
        emailAddress: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
        },
        password: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
        },
      });
```

and here is the router:

```
    router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { fullName, emailAddress, password } = req.body;
  bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then((hash) => {
    Users.create({
      fullName: fullName,
      emailAddress: emailAddress,
      password: hash,
    });
    res.json("User, Success");
  });
});
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add unique constrains on DB level, and handle `SequelizeUniqueConstraintError` to return validation message to a user during creation.

If you are using `sequelize.sync()` to apply models changes on DB schema then you can define the constrains like this:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Users = sequelize.define('Users', {
    fullName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true // unique constrain of the column `fullName`
    },
    emailAddress: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true // unique constrain of the column `emailAddress`
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }, {
    // define constrain like this if you need combination of columns unique
    // indexes: [
    //   {
    //     unique: true,
    //     fields: ['fullName', 'emailAddress']
    //   }
    // ]
  });

  return Users;
};
```

If you create DB schema using migrations you can create the constrains like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.addColumn('Users', 'fullName', {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true // unique constrain of the column `fullName`
    });
    await queryInterface.addColumn('Users', 'emailAddress', {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true // unique constrain of the column `emailAddress `
    });
    // define constrain like this if you need combination of columns unique
    // return queryInterface.addConstraint('Users', ['fullName', 'emailAddress'], {
    //   'type': 'unique',
    //   'name': 'UK_Users_fullName_emailAddress'
    // })
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.removeColumn('Users', 'emailAddress');
    await queryInterface.removeColumn('Users', 'fullName');
    // return queryInterface.removeConstraint('Users', 'UK_Users_fullName_emailAddress')
  }
}
```

so in this approach DB will never let you add duplicate entries.

**Update #1**

If I get it right, your code snippet is an express router. If so then you need to check wether a user with email or fullName exists, like this with sequelize:

```js
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { fullName, emailAddress, password } = req.body;

  const user = await Users.findOne({ fullName, emailAddress });

  if (!user) {
    res.status(400).send({ error: "This email is in use by someone els, please try something else, thanks." });
  } else {
    bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then((hash) => {
      Users.create({
        fullName: fullName,
        emailAddress: emailAddress,
        password: hash,
      });
      res.json("User, Success");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for your response. I tried, this but still I am getting doulicates.

Comment: I have a problem with checking if a user is existing or no, please take a look at answer below, you may understand the problem.

Comment: @MurtazaHassani See **Update #1**

Comment: Hey, it didn't work, so changed my database, now i am not allowed to create doublicate user, but it gives and error says:

  original: Error: Duplicate entry 'Booker' for key 'users.fullName_UNIQUE'

Comment: @MurtazaHassani it is expected error from DB, but most probably you're not willing to show it in FE, so you have to catch it in BE with try/catch block and return user friendly validation message.

Answer (score 0):

you can start in router.post.
Check if there is a user with this email by querying the database, and if it exists then throw an error saying the user is already here.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, could you please give an example? because i am quite new using nodejs

Comment: please read the documentation first : https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html then try something. then ask on stack overflow if you experience a bug :)

Answer (score 0):

this is what I've tried.

```
 router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { fullName, emailAddress, password } = req.body;
  if (fullName && emailAddress) {
    console.log(
      "This email is in use by someone els, please try something else, thanks."
    );
  } else {
    bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then((hash) => {
      Users.create({
        fullName: fullName,
        emailAddress: emailAddress,
        password: hash,
      });
      res.json("User, Success");
    });
  }
});
```

now it is working but i need to display some message in the ui for the user.